# What is the order of subject and object in pub/sub?

Tags: rx-java, publish-subscribe

I'm using `RxJava` to write some pub/sub code.
I found we must use the pattern below:

```
observable.subscribe(observer)
```

but in my understanding, we should say a sentence like "observer subscribes to observable". So why isn't the code designed like:

```
observer.subscribe(observable)
```

Is this order of observer and observable reasonable?

If for some tech reasons something should be in the control of observable so that we could only use observable as subject and use obsever as object, why don't we use another word like:

```
observable.publish(observer)
```

I think in this way it could be more logical in grammer and easy-reading. So I was wondering if there was any other consideration make people use "observable.subscribe(observer)".

Comment: Makes no sense. `subscribe` contains or triggers the logic to feed the observer with events and thus the `observable` should be in control. If the method `subscribe` is on `observer`, this is impossible.

Comment: observable.subscribe != pub/sub. Think of this operation as bottom to top, an observable is executed only when an observer subscribes to it. This is true for all cold observables. An observable is a dormant piece of code unless something makes it run and the thing which makes it run is a subscription from an Observer.

Comment: Consider going to a grocery shop, the grocer (Observable) does not hand random items to people who are just passing by, only those people (Observers) who enter the shop and ask for an item triggers the grocer (Observable) too look into shelves and hand over the item to the customer (Observer) and the grocer might as well wrap your item with packaging using a map function for each item (Bonus)

Answer (score 0):

Just read it as `Observable` `subscribe` with `Observer`.

If you had to do the opposite you couldn't have different callbacks for success, error, complete and you had to create the object before using it. It would be really bad for readability.